# Best way to increase RowHeight on a DevExpress GridView?

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress

Sorry If I make a mistake in my explanation, I'm new and interning.

I have a Winforms application which a VB Front End that uses DevExpress.

It has a gridView which Represents a DataTable.

One of these columns in the GridView is used for descriptions,  I believe it's a `repositoryItemMemoEdit` Column and it's used to display text ranging from a few lines to entire paragraphs.

I've found that setting the `GridView.OptionsView.RowAutoHeight = True` allows my row to display the text in its entirety, However sometimes the text is just too big.

I'm looking for the best way to make the row display the first line or two and have the rest of the text either display via a tool-tip which appears on mouse over or have a show more and show less button which expands and contracts the row to fit the text or only show the first line. The solution could even be making the first line a hyperlink and make it open a new popup window lol.

Can anybody just point me in the right direction? I know next to nothing on DevExpress, and most of their forum answers are just blocks of code without a visual representation, so I can't even see if it's what I'm looking for...

Thank you.

edit: TLDR: What's the best way to allow the user to see more of the text when they wish, when within a GridView?

Comment: [This](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114724/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Getting-Started/Walkthroughs/Grid-View-Columns-Rows-and-Cells/Tutorial-Auto-Row-Height) should help you

Comment: So that's the guide I was looking at. I got up to the point that I can show the first line of the text or the text in its entirety. But it does not explain or show how I could allow the user to to choose between seeing only the single line or the entire text. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Do you need the GridView to be editable (user edits current data)?

Comment: Nope, it's already populated with data. There are checkboxes in certain columns however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution could even be making the first line a hyperlink and make it open a new popup window.

Subscribe to the `GridView.RowCellClick` event, to the `GridView.ShowingEditor` event and display a `XtraMessageBox` with the cell's content:

```
Imports DevExpress.XtraEditors
Imports DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid

Private Sub GridView1_RowCellClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellClickEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCellClick
    If e.Column.Equals(GridView1.Columns("DesiredColumn")) Then
        XtraMessageBox.Show(GridView1.GetFocusedDataRow()("DesiredColumn").ToString())
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GridView1_ShowingEditor(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles GridView1.ShowingEditor
    If GridView1.FocusedColumn.Equals(GridView1.Columns("DesiredColumn")) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Form]

Cell clicked:
[image: Message]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best approach would be to handle [GridView.CustomDrawCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomDrawCell.event) event and handle this manually in [ToolTipController.GetActiveObjectInfo](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.ToolTipController.GetActiveObjectInfo.event) event.

```
private void GridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Column.FieldName == "DesiredColumn")
        {
            // handle display logic here, this is just POC
            var row = GridView1.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);
            var text = row["DesiredColumn"].ToString();

            if (text.Length > 100) {
              e.DisplayText = text.Substring(0, 100) + "...";
              e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }


private void toolTipController1_GetActiveObjectInfo(object sender, ToolTipControllerGetActiveObjectInfoEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTipControlInfo info;
        var gv = this.GridControl1.GetViewAt(e.ControlMousePosition) as GridView;
        if (gv == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var hInfo = gv.CalcHitInfo(e.ControlMousePosition);

        if ((e.SelectedControl is GridControl))
        {
            if (hInfo.InRowCell)
            {
                if (hInfo.Column == gv.Columns["DesiredColumn"])
                {
                    var row = gv.GetDataRow(hInfo.RowHandle);
                    var text = row["DesiredColumn"].ToString;
                        info = new ToolTipControlInfo(this.GridControl1, text);
                        e.Info = info;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: OP is using VB!